# How to re-cast char* to integer after using sprintf_s()?

Tags: c, casting

This is my casting from int to char*:

```
char* str = malloc(sizeof("0000"));
int int_ = 10;
sprintf_s(str, sizeof("0000"), "%04d", int_);
//str == "0010"
```

And I want to re-cast `str` to int back (`int_new == 10`).
How could I do this?

Comment: Sorry about my previous answer, you still need 5 characters for a null-terminated string.

Comment: You cannot cast `str` correctly from `char*` to an integer value. You'll need to use `atoi` or `strtol` or similar.

Comment: A *cast* is a specific operator in C; it is a type name in parentheses. A cast performs a *conversion*, which is a function or operation that seeks to produce the same value in a different representation. Formatting a number as a string with `%04d` performs a conversion from `int` to a decimal numeral in a string. For the reverse, you want a function that takes a string containing a decimal numeral and produces an `int` with the same value. `atoi` does this but has limitations regarding error handling. `strtol` is better but requires more code, including a conversion from `long` to `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil. it solves my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strlen to find the size of a string. Remember to add +1 for the nul byte at the end of the string. Otherwise, snprintf will fail.

```
int max_size = 5 ;
char* str = malloc(max_size);
int int_ = 10;
sprintf_s(str, max_size, "%04d", int_);

int int_new = atoi(str) ;
```

Alternative

```
int int_ = 10;

char buff[32] ;   // make it big enough to worst case
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%04d", int_) ;
char *str = strdup(buff) ;

int int_new = atoi(str) ;
```

Comment: I need to cast char* to integer

Comment: There is no 'casting' from string to int. You probably mean you want to parse the result. See atoi above. But why not new_int = int_ ?

Comment: Yes, may be. But ```strtol()``` helps me. Why ```new_int = int```? Because these variables are placed in different functions and I have strict signature of these functions and can't pass some other variables.